# Mongoose unsettable properties

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

Is there a way I can include a property in a schema, such as a `created` timestamp, but forbid users from setting that value in creation (always use the default)? This is specifically for an API where I want to have a `created` value in the schema but want to always override the request body's value with the current timestamp. Example:

```js
const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});
```

In this schema, how could I make it so that even if a value is passed during initialization, it is overridden with `Date.now`?

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like you want to use the "createdAt" timestamp, if it's that, you can use the immutable property:

```
const Model = mongoose.model('Test', new Schema({
  name: String,
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    immutable: true // Make `createdAt` immutable
  }
}, { timestamps: true }));
```